# Mostrar variável em local específico com um div

Tags: php, html

Tenho este while onde criei uma variável antes do while para depois obter o total de uma coluna:

```
$Total = 0;

    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

        $teste = $rows_cursos['Horas Consumidas'];
        $Total = $Total + $teste;

$tabela3 .= '<tr>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['DataRegisto'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['codigoutente'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['nome'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['descricaovalencia'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Data'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Inicio'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Fim'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Colaborador'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Horas Consumidas'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '</tr>'; 

}

$tabela3 .= '</tr>';

$tabela3 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela3 .= '</table>';

$tabela3 .= '</div>';

echo $tabela3;

echo '<strong>Total de Horas Consumidas:</strong> '. $Total;
```

Mas este resultado que aparece rodeado a vermelho, queria que aparecesse debaixo da última coluna da tabela como aponta a seta, uma vez que é a soma das horas dessa coluna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja que após o `while` você está fechando a `</tr>` desnecessariamente:

```
$tabela3 .= '</tr>'; 

}

$tabela3 .= '</tr>'; <-- fechando novamente a TR
```

As linhas já são fechadas dentro do `while`.

No lugar dessa linha `$tabela3 .= '</tr>';` você pode inserir uma nova linha com `<td colspan="9">`, onde `9` representa o número de colunas, criando uma linha com apenas uma `<td>` abrangendo as 9 colunas da tabela. Coloque também `align="right"` para alinhar o texto à direita. O código ficaria assim:

```
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

        $teste = $rows_cursos['Horas Consumidas'];
        $Total = $Total + $teste;

$tabela3 .= '<tr>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['DataRegisto'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['codigoutente'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['nome'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['descricaovalencia'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Data'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Inicio'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Fim'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Colaborador'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Horas Consumidas'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '</tr>'; 

}

$tabela3 .= '<tr>';
$tabela3 .= '<td colspan="9" align="right">';
$tabela3 .= '<strong>Total de Horas Consumidas:</strong> '. $Total;
$tabela3 .= '</td>';
$tabela3 .= '</tr>';

$tabela3 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela3 .= '</table>';

$tabela3 .= '</div>';

echo $tabela3;
```